# JAWS Screenreader % sign and superscript tag

Tags: html, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I am having an issue where  tags are not being read when using JAWS.

I've managed to narrow the problem to the follow:

```
<div>100<sup>1</sup></div>
```

Will be read correctly as "100 superscript 1 end superscript"

But when I add a % sign:

```
<div>100%<sup>1</sup></div>
```

It will read it as "100% 1" and omit announcement of the superscript tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `&sup1;` instead of `<sup>1</sup>`.

http://accessibleculture.org/research-files/character-references/jaws-we-all.php